# Copy a file to absolute path

Tags: wix

How can I tell WiX to copy a file to a specific path that is outside my applications installation path during installation?

I need to copy a file from my applications installation directory into the directory of another application, and so far I'm not able to figure out the syntax.  I know the syntax below is wrong, but this is pseudo code for what I want to do:

```
<CopyFile Id="MyCopyFile" SourceDirectory="..\Path\To\My\Source\File" SourceName="myfile.dat" DestinationDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\OtherProgram\TargetDir" DestinationName="myfile.dat"/>
```

This install will only run on specific machines so absolute paths are fine.

Comment: Re: Docs. WiX builds Windows Installer packages. The docs focus on simplifications WiX makes over Windows Installer tables and actions. Be sure to follow any links to the Windows Installer documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy file from setup location to another location in wix on install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363785/copy-file-from-setup-location-to-another-location-in-wix-on-install)