# Wix Burn - Save Installer after installation

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I have a custom wix burn installer that I have made and it works well except for I can't figure out how to do one thing: save the wix burn installer exe to a location after the installation is done.

Here is my scenario:

1. My software can be distributed across multiple servers, but one server is the "core" server.
2. I plan to update the core server and then have the core server push software updates to the other server.
3. To have the core server distribute the update, it has to keep a copy of the Wix Burn Installer EXE somewhere for distribution.  This is what I can't figure out.

Using the built in variable WixBundleOriginalSource, I can find the original installer exe.  However, when I try to copy it during ApplyComplete (I don't want to save it unless it successfully installed), I get an access denied trying to copy the file (which makes sense since the burn installer is not running as an admin).

How can I accomplish this - copy the original wix burn installer exe after the installation is complete without permission issues?  I get that 99.99% of the time, all file operations should happen inside an MSI, but I can't have an MSI deploy the original Wix Burn Installer, so I am stumped.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - here is how I worked around it.  I passed the WixBundleOriginalSource to one of the MSIs and then added a CopyFile element to do the copy in the MSI...

[Copy file from setup location to another location in wix on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363785/copy-file-from-setup-location-to-another-location-in-wix-on-install)